# Flat-ui select dropdown is not functioning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, markup, flat

I am using Flat-UI (http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/) to aid with the front-end elements of a small MeteorJS App I am building.

The problem I am having is that the Select Dropdown is not working. And I would like to know how to get the option value.
Please see the below Markup:

```
<div class="select2-container form-control select select-primary" id="s2id_autogen1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
        <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">My Profile</span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
        <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
            <b role="presentation"></b>
        </span>
    </a>
    <label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2">
</div>
<select class="form-control select select-primary" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
    <optgroup label="Profile">
        <option value="0">My Profile</option>
        <option value="1">My Friends</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="System">
        <option value="2">Messages</option>
        <option value="3">My Settings</option>
        <option value="4">Logout</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is what we have in flatui document. But the select dropdown is not functioning, can someone help me to make it work and pull value from the options?

Answer (score 0):

> We have made a custom select due to the inability of styling the system one. It is based on the Select2 plug-in with the source slightly modified to meet Bootstrap naming convention.

Select2 3.5.2

Check this:
http://select2.github.io/select2/

```
$("#selectList")
.on("change", function(e) { log("change "+JSON.stringify({val:e.val, added:e.added, removed:e.removed})); })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation well you will notice you have manually add a select2 call to transform all selects.

E.g. like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("select").select2({dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse'});
});
```